# Python 2.7 keeping console in the background open

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

At the begining i would like to state that i did look for an answer before posting my question, but if i missed anything I'm really sorry.

Ok to the point.
I'm trying to create a tool that will monitor behaviour of my 2 external devices comunicating over BT(communication over BT i have pretty much solved). but what i'm strugling with is monitoring them.
So Manually i open cmdline 2 times and from there i use putty to connect to devices and do stuff.

Now I want(and pretty much need) to do the manual part in python. So i tried using subprocess.Popen to connect to cmdline(and from there to putty) but the problem is that this only works as request/response. what i need is to open (and keep) cmdline streamlike connection and pass and receive commands/response without closing.

P.S. I'm using windows enviroment and python 2.7.

Thank You for any response.
Kind Regards.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and why it didn't work?  Code snippets would be helpful.

Comment: Look into `pexpect`: https://gist.github.com/anthonyeden/8488763#file-python-wexpect

Comment: do you want to open the console automatically (using python), to provide the necessary input manually? Or do you want to perform interactions with the subprocesses automatically (no manual input). Do you need to see the interactions (in real time) in any case?

Comment: @ Joel, It did work but just not as i wanted it to. so the console instance was initialized i passed parameters and then it gave me response and then it was closed. Sorry i cannot provide the code at the moment as i'm on a Bussiness trip.
Regards,

@ J.F.Sebastian. I want the console to be opened in the background using python, and pass and receive stuff autiomatically. The only manual thing that user should be available to do manually is open the app, and review the reports that will be available after data processing and displayed on the Gui (that part is already implemented.
Regards